# Can "sir" be used to address female officers?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The use of the term *sir* as a form of address for men, especially those of higher rank or status, is discussed in several prior questions including [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28309/usage-of-and-equivalents-of-sir). They all indicate that the term is reserved to males, and that there are a number of related terms for females, such as *ma'am*.

A review of the first dozen online dictionaries at onelook.com confirms that *sir* is strictly reserved for male addressees. For example [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sir?view=uk) defines it as

> used as a polite or respectful way of addressing a man, especially one in a position of authority: *excuse me, sir*

On several recent television shows in the US, the term *sir* has been used by a police officer to address his or her supervisor who was female. In the context, the use was sincere and was not objected to by the superior.

Has the use of *sir* when addressing a superior female in a military or quasi-military setting become acceptable, or is this merely literary license?

Comment: Interesting parenthetical note in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir): _When addressing a male superior (e.g. Officer or Warrant Officer, but not usually a non-commissioned officer, in the military), "sir" is used as a short form of address. (Despite its use in many fictional works, this is not a term used for female superiors, who are addressed as "ma'am")._

Comment: Having had some experience with the U.S. Navy, I can assure you that calling a female superior officer "sir" would pretty quickly get you your a** handed to you. "Ma'am" is correct, I assure you.

Comment: Can you give specific citations of some of these recent TV shows, so we can see the context for ourselves?

Comment: @NateEldredge In episodes of *Castle*, Detective Becket refers to her female captain as *Sir*.  I have a general recall of another such pattern but cannot recall the exact show. There are references on the web to the use of *sir* for female officers in some Star Trek movies or episodes.

Comment: This is not a question about English, but about military (or paramilitary) protocols or etiquette. The answer will vary from organization to organization.

Comment: In the show *Castle*, Beckett's boss [specifically requests to be addressed as Sir or Captain](http://castle.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_Gates), showing that this form of address is not standard in the setting of the show.

Comment: In the movie Halo, not the game that I know of, one guy addressed the high ranked female officer as 'sir'. Though this is just a movie it does not prove anything, I was wanting to join the air force and was confused by this problem also..I just don't want to say the wrong thing and then get yelled at.

Comment: Anyone remember Madonna’s _Girlie Show_ tour in 1992? There was a bit there which was quite wannabe-military in style, where Madonna ordered her ‘cadets’ to do something and they replied, “Yes sir!”. She then replied, “That’s _Yes Sir Mrs. Sir Yes Sir_!”. Not something I imagine is very widespread in the real world, but I’ve always wanted to address a superior with a good _Yes Sir Mrs. Sir Yes Sir_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, that reminds me of the Geordie dialect (Newcastle-upon-Tyne, NE England), in which you would address a man as "man" as in "gan canny, man" (meaning "take care") and a woman as "pet". However the "man" has become such an ingrained way of ending a sentence that it's not uncommon to hear "gan canny, pet, man", "gan canny, man, pet" or even "gan canny, man, pet, man".

Comment: On the TV show Castle, Beckett, a female officer, often addresses her superior female boss as "sir", in a respectful context.

Comment: Even if it was sincere, it might be some kind of running joke between them. Maybe she does not like Ma'am.

Comment: And I just heard it used in the Canadian show "The Listener" by a male Lieutenant to his immediate female superior. In case it matters the episode is "The Blue Line" just under halfway through.

Comment: Picard also refers to a female admiral as "sir" in TNG, and in Fullmetal Alchemist, all of the characters call Major General Armstrong (a woman) "sir."

Comment: If you really thought addressing a woman as "Sir" acceptable, should you not be able to both cite and justify a few instances?

That's not "merely…" nor any "literary license"; it's a mistake.

Some episodes of Star Trek: Voyager - 500 years in the future - address female Captain Janeway as "Sir…" but in some way not explained, her case is special. Unless I was asleep on watch, no other senior women are called "Sir…"
   
However many TV shows use the term "sir" for female superiors, with of without objection, how could you or anyone seem "sincere" while stripping "sir" of its capital?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The U.S. Army [Field Manual FM 7-21.13](http://armypubs.army.mil/doctrine/DR_pubs/DR_a/pdf/fm7_21x13.pdf) Section 4.18 states:

> 4-18. A soldier addressing a higher ranking officer uses the word sir
>   or ma’am in the same manner as a polite civilian speaking with a
>   person to whom he wishes to show respect. In the military service, the
>   matter of who says sir or ma’am to whom is clearly defined; in
>   civilian life it is largely a matter of discretion. In the case of
>   NCOs and soldiers, we address them by their rank because they’ve
>   earned that rank.

Therefore, the military protocol follows the civilian protocol of respectful addresses, with the additional requirement that the greeting is mandatory when addressing superior officers.

Since in normal day English one does not generally refer to females as "sir", the same would apply in a military context.

Answer (score 18):

As commented by @MετάEd, this seems a question of military etiquette.  So allow to me offer this answer based on what I have observed.

I am not a member of the military myself, but I spend a lot of time working at a U.S. military base in a building that houses many male and female members of the military, members of every service (Army, Navy, Air Force, Marines, and Coast Guard), as well as members of the Canadian and Mexican military.

In every case that I have witnessed (where the speakers are using English), women are addressed as "ma'am."  Additionally, half of the people answer their phones with a phrase similar to, "Hello this is Private John Doe; how may I help you sir or ma'am?"

As a side note, I wish that my French and Spanish were better so that I could comment on how the users of those languages address each other.

Answer (score 7):

Sir is for men. Most women would be offended if you called them sir (with the possible exception of some supreme feminists). Like John M. Landsberg commented, "Ma'am" is what you want to use unless you're asking for trouble.

Comment: I don't know any feminists who would advocate a “sir” default.

Comment: Yeah, @Bobo, I think you have profoundly misunderstand extremist feminism.

Comment: How so, @Codeswitcher? Feminists are people who believe women and men have equal rights, yes? Then some of these people might also believe that they should also have equal titles.

Comment: @Bobo First, there definitely are feminists who want to be addressed as "sir".  For instance, the male ones.  Secondly you're assuming that the women under discussion would want to achieve "equal" titles by adopting the male one.  And more specifically, you're talking about the very subset which spells their sex "womyn" so as not to have "man" in the word: I don't think demanding to be called by a male honorific is likely to be high on their agenda for equality.  Why don't you look into it and report back.

Comment: 1. I was obviously talking about women feminists (since I said earlier in the sentence, "most women"). 2. You are generalizing feminists yourself. Not all of them want to be called "womyn". And I am talking very small cases of people here, so just because you've never met one doesn't mean they don't exist. And 3. I actually have met a woman who thought being called "ma'am" was derogatory and preferred being called sir. Not sure anyone actually did, but that was her preference.  (Also, why are you bothering a year-old post?)

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Season 4, episode 1, on January 10, 2011, in the show "Castle", Penny Johnson Jerald, as the new captain, Victoria "Iron" Gates, insists upon the use of "sir".

The first time I heard it used on TV was in 1992, Star Trek The Next Generation, the episode "The First Duty" when the trial president, a female, was addressed as "sir" by all others.

In NCIS, did Jenny, as Director, tell her subordinate she was to be addressed as "sir or director" ?  I think so.

I never have heard it used in real life, but wish there was a female equivalent.  Female terms tend to assume new, negative, meanings.  From Dictionary.com:

**Madam:**  1. ( often initial capital letter ) a polite term of address to a woman, originally used only to a woman of rank or authority: Madam President; May I help you, madam?
2.
the woman in charge of a household: Is the madam at home?
3.
**the woman in charge of a house of prostitution.**

The derivative of madam, ma'am, has not changed so much, but it is not a term often used other than to royalty or by a subservient ... not a typical word in US English.

Comment: What bearing would TV space operas have on this discussion? Do you suppose that all manufactured usages in speculative fiction should in some way govern English usage?

Comment: "Ma'am" not typical in US English? "Ma'am" is certainly used in formal settings throughout the USA.   Examples: In court, I may address a woman judge as "Your Honor" or "Ma'am", I may address a woman opposing lawyer as "Counsel", or "Ma'am". "Ma'am" is still commonly used in the southern states as an address for any adult woman, especially one who is older than the speaker.

Comment: I highly doubt we can make a worse answer... TV shows references... And saying that Ma'am is not US En... HAHAHA Hat off for making me laugh!

Comment: Not only have you answered the question wrong, but also you have bravely chosen to answer a different question wrong also.
Sir, Ma'am are in common use in LARGE parts of the USA.